# QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext works in PyQt5 but not PySide2

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

I'm working on a log console widget and to be able to achieve what I want I need something that can handle a VERY LARGE amount of line, I tried QPlainTextEdit (And QTextEdit) and they are not good enough for what I need, too slow when there's too much text.
-> Right now, everything works, I just have an issue with how selection highlight is drawn.

My implementation is based on a QTextDocument that hold all the text and I use it to draw it's content in a simple QWidget subclass. It works beautifully except the selection that does not seems to work in PySide2 but works as expected in PyQt5.
In fact it seems that PySide2 is missing the `selection` attribute on the `QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext`. I tried to have a look to the woboq C++ source code but I can't find how to reimplement what is missing as it's using the D-Pointer (Q_D)

There's an MRE so you can test, you can just replace the import for `PyQt5` or `PySide2` and then the text selection will work only in PyQt5.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

LOREM_IPSUM = \
'''
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Morbi dictum ligula mi, ut venenatis urna molestie et. 
Phasellus velit nunc, consequat nec felis ut, egestas pulvinar mi. 
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 
Mauris eget faucibus est, vitae suscipit neque. 
Curabitur elementum tellus nec mauris rutrum laoreet. 
Duis condimentum consequat dui sit amet semper. 
Nam varius aliquet nibh, sit amet molestie ex scelerisque a. 
Donec sodales, sapien non consequat luctus, ante quam pretium nibh, sed egestas augue nunc et augue.
'''


class TextEdit(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, document, parent=None):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__(parent=None)
        
        self._document = document
        self._selectionStart = 0
        self._selectionEnd = 0
                
        self.cur = QtGui.QTextCursor(self._document)
        
        self._selectionFormat = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        self._selectionFormat.setBackground(QtGui.QColor('#2B4A69'))
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        
        # This is the problematic area
        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
        selection = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.Selection()
        selection.cursor = self.cur
        selection.format = self._selectionFormat
        # print(ctx.selections)  # Works in PyQt5, not PySide2 where the attribute is missing.
        ctx.selections = [selection]
        
        self._document.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        start = end = self._document.documentLayout().hitTest(event.pos(), QtCore.Qt.FuzzyHit)
        self.cur.setPosition(start)
        self.cur.setPosition(end, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        
        self.update()
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        end = self._document.documentLayout().hitTest(event.pos(), QtCore.Qt.FuzzyHit)
        self.cur.setPosition(end, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        
        self.update()
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() is not None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
    doc.setPlainText(LOREM_IPSUM)
    
    widget = TextEdit(doc)
    widget.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The reason why I need `PySide2` and not `PyQt5` is because I'm developing a tool for Autodesk Maya that ship with PySide2, so I need to stick with it, also that's what we use at my job so I don't have the choice.

PS: A ticket was opened 3 years ago but no answer and no workaround: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1220

Comment: The implementation is mostly in *gui/text/qtextdocumentlayout.cpp*, which defines a private layout class used by `QTextDocument`. However, a reimplementation of its `draw()` method doesn't look feasible, since it indirectly depends on a lot of other methods and classes which aren't publicly accessible. Effectively, you'd have to write your own layout subclass from scratch to work around the selection issue. Your only real hope is to get the `PaintContext` class fixed in PySide6, and then try to persuade the devs to backport it to PySide2.

Comment: PS: if the bug report doesn't get any attention, I suggest you try the [pyside mailing list](https://lists.qt-project.org/listinfo/pyside) instead. But note that your current MRE isn't valid, since it doesn't create an application object.

Comment: Oh you're right, when creating UI for Maya the Application already exists, it's Maya itself, but you're right, to test in other conditions it's required.
About getting it fixed for PySide6 it would definitely be something to do, I don't think it will be backported to PySide2 but I can ask. But anyway, for me, I think Autodesk will not include this change in Maya...